# Unable to find MD5 in calcite SQL

Tags: apache-calcite

I am trying to find MD5 checksum value for a column in calcite but the query is throwing an error and i could not trace it.

Please find the results of the sample table and query with error below,

```
    0: jdbc:calcite:model=src/test/resources/mode> SELECT * FROM emps;
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+------+---------+---------+------------+
| EMPNO | NAME  | DEPTNO | GENDER |     CITY      | EMPID | AGE  | SLACKER | MANAGER |  JOINEDAT  |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+------+---------+---------+------------+
| 100   | Fred  | 10     |        |               | 30    | 25   | true    | false   | 1996-08-03 |
| 110   | Eric  | 20     | M      | San Francisco | 3     | 80   |         | false   | 2001-01-01 |
| 110   | John  | 40     | M      | Vancouver     | 2     | null | false   | true    | 2002-05-03 |
| 120   | Wilma | 20     | F      |               | 1     | 5    |         | true    | 2005-09-07 |
| 130   | Alice | 40     | F      | Vancouver     | 2     | null | false   | true    | 2007-01-01 |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+------+---------+---------+------------+
5 rows selected (0.02 seconds)
0: jdbc:calcite:model=src/test/resources/mode> SELECT md5(cast(name as VARCHAR)) FROM emps;
Error: Error while executing SQL "SELECT md5(cast(name as VARCHAR)) FROM emps": From line 1, column 8 to line 1, column 33: No match found for function signature MD5(<CHARACTER>) (state=,code=0)
```

both queries throws the same error.

```
SELECT md5(cast(name as VARCHAR)) FROM emps;
SELECT md5(name) FROM emps;
```

Answer (score 1):

MD5 isn't an standard SQL function, therefore Calcite doesn't enable it by default.

To use it you need to explicitly set the `FUN` connection parameter to an engine that supports MD5 (i.e. MySQL, PostgresSQL, Google BigQuery).

The [documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#dialect-specific-operators) has more information about the available operators.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive that error anytime you try to use a library-specific function (such as MD5) without configuring for whichever library supports that function. If you look at Calcite's MD5 operator tests [here](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/main/testkit/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/test/SqlOperatorTest.java#L4297), you will see that the first test is expected to fail given that a library has not been set. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).